# If total is between two numbers echo statement, else if between different set of numbers echo a different statement, etc

Tags: php, sql, if-statement

**Answered**
I was able to get this to work using the example posted by Glavić. Thank you everyone for your tips, they are all very useful.

**Original Question**
I am terrible with figuring out if/else statements. I have looked at multiple tutorials and just can't get what I'm trying to do work. I need this:
If total amount of points is less than # state that no title is achieved
If total amount is between # and # state what title that would be
If total amount is between higher # and # state what title that would be
etc.

The adding of total points works just fine but I can't figure out how to get the correct title for the total points to show. I have included the code for getting totalpoints as well in case it can be combined with what I am trying to do. Any help greatly appreciated

This works just fine:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT points, SUM(points) AS totalpoints FROM competition WHERE id = $id"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<b>";
    echo $row['totalpoints'];
    echo "pts</b>";
}?>
```

This does not work:
(it says Hall of Fame regardless of what the point total is)

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT points, SUM(points) AS totalpoints FROM competition WHERE id = $id"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($titled = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

if ($titled <= 999)
 {echo ", not titled";}

elseif (($titled == 1000) && ($titled <= 1999)) 
 {echo ", Champion";}

elseif (($titled >= 2000) && ($titled <= 2999)) 
 {echo ", Grand Champion";}

elseif (($titled >= 3000) && ($titled <= 3999)) 
 {echo ", Honor Champion";}

elseif (($titled >= 4000) && ($titled <= 5999)) 
 {echo ", Regional Champion";}

elseif (($titled >= 6000) && ($titled <= 7999)) 
 {echo ", State Champion";}

elseif (($titled >= 8000) && ($titled <= 9999)) 
 {echo ", National Champion";}

elseif (($titled >= 10000) && ($titled <= 19999)) 
 {echo ", World Champion";}

elseif ($titled >= 20000) 
 {echo ", Hall of Fame";}

}?>
```

Comment: `== 1000` should be `>= 1000`.

Comment: You don't need all the `>=` parts of your tests. The previous test will already eliminate the cases where the value is lower than this range. Actually, get rid of all the `if`s and just use an array that you index by `floor($titled['totalpoints']/1000)`

Answer (score 1):

`$titled = mysql_fetch_array($result)` gives you an array which is not comparable to integers. You will need to use `$titled['totalpoints']`.

Comment: Sorry for rolling back, Dan, but your edit did not really improve formatting.

Answer (score 1):

A little nicer code (without all that `if` statements):

```
$titles = array(
        0 => 'not titled',
     1000 => 'Champion',
     2000 => 'Grand Champion',
     3000 => 'Honor Champion',
     4000 => 'Regional Champion',
     6000 => 'State Champion',
     8000 => 'National Champion',
    10000 => 'World Champion',
    20000 => 'Hall of Fame',
);
$titles = array_reverse($titles, true);

while ($titled = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    foreach ($titles as $score => $title) {
        if ($titled['totalpoints'] >= $score) break;
    }
    echo ', ' . $title;
}
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/51548).

Comment: Fantastic! I used your code and it does exactly what I wanted, plus it looks a heck of a lot nicer. Thank you Glavić.